# Select from table when stored procedure parameter empty

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

As my title suggests, I have a stored procedure query where I pass in a parameter and it returns data based on that parameter. However, if I pass a blank, I would like that everything in the table be returned.

I have posted some code, as you see....the `@id` parameter selects only those of that ID correctly but I'd like to know what I should add (or remove) so if this parameter is blank everything is return.

Thank you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_stuent]
    @id varchar(25)
AS
    CREATE TABLE dbo.#usp_holder (name varchar(25),
                                  id char(5),
                                  class varchar (25),
                                  grade numeric(5)
                                 )


    INSERT INTO #usp_ holder (name, id, class)
        SELECT 
            name, id, class
        FROM
            dbo.classmaster 
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.classtypes ON classmaster.type = classtypes.type
        WHERE 
            classmaster.id = @id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_stuent]
@id varchar(25)
AS

CREATE TABLE dbo.#usp_holder
(
name  varchar(25),
id char(5) = null,
class varchar (25)
)
```

You may want to add another condition to check if the input is an `empty string` but not `null`. Like this:

```
IF (@id = '')
BEGIN
SET @id = null
END

INSERT INTO 
#usp_ holder (name,id,class
)
Select name,id,class
from dbo.classmaster 
inner join dbo.classtypes
on classmaster.type= classtypes.type
WHERE classmaster.id = ISNULL(@id, classmaster.id)
```

Comment: Coalesce is also an option.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx